# Make image fluid with responsive design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I actually know how to fluid an image with responsive design. But, my problem is not simple. I using scale width function of parent `div` to append width of `image` like that :

```
 function OnImageLoad(evt){somthing....}
<div class="parent">
 <img style="left: 0px; top: -20px;" onload="OnImageLoad(event);" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pHWQ1Wp63GQ/Uk3TJLa9FbI/AAAAAAAAACg/_JUXOxweYY8/s1600/edu2.jpg" width="270" height="175">
</div>
```

Now, I want run event on image `onload="OnImageLoad(envent);"` again if window resizing

```
$(window).resize(function(){ ??? });
```

Help me to fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of using javascript to get fluidity, why cant you set the heights and widths of the images in percentage??

Comment: Because images were loaded from posts to make the thumbnails. For the insure of thumbnail quality, I must use scale function to generate size of image from parent div.

Comment: you could use window.onresize and iterate throught the image collection

Comment: Thanks Arun. But you can detail more?

Comment: window.onresize is triggered when you resize your window. capture the event and run your scaling function inside that for all your thumbnails as the onload event would do on each of them

Comment: Please help with attached file here: http://www.mediafire.com/?wngm0gg25m3ps1d. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the images a special class (if not all need to be triggered).
(Use a timer in the resize function to support browsers from triggering it multiple times.)

```
$(window).resize(function(){

      //get the function out of the onload attribute
      var onloadFunction = $("img.[specialclass]").attr("onload");
      //Execute it
      eval(onloadFunction);
});
```

But on the other hand if you only want to scale the images. 
The ratio keeps the same in this example by the padding-bottom.

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:66%;
}
```

Comment: Updated it.. Try this :)

Comment: I have tried, but it still the same result. Thanks for your attempt to help me.

Comment: Please help with attached file here: http://www.mediafire.com/?wngm0gg25m3ps1d. Thanks.